# Python target a variable given the string

Tags: python, string, variables, jupyter-notebook, store

EDIT: The general idea is to store all the variables in my Jupyter Notebook using %store magic in order to use %store -r to get them all back to the next session.

I am trying to use:

```
% store
```

and I need to store variables. With:

```
dir()
```

I obtain a list of strings with all the variables' names I created until that line like:

```
['a','b','c']
```

Is there a way to perform a:

```
%store a
%store b
%store c
```

Knowing the strings of the variables?
I tried with this:

```
for i in dir():
    %store eval(i)
```

but it gives: UsageError: Unknown variable 'eval(i)'
How can I deal with that? Is there a way to save all the local environment in Jupyter Notebook for a next use?

EDIT:

```
for i in dir():
    %store locals()[i]
```

Gives: UsageError: Unknown variable 'locals()[i]'

Comment: Do you want to store it?

Comment: Can't you just call the function directly (you'd have to look up the docs, but presumably `%store i` just calls something like `StoreMagics.store('i', i)`)? Or do you need to actually use the %magic for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @abarnert you can run the line magic programmatically, e.g.:

```
In []:
import IPython
store = IPython.get_ipython().find_line_magic('store')

a = b = c = 10
for i in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    store(i)

Out []:
Stored 'a' (int)
Stored 'b' (int)
Stored 'c' (int)
```

The problem with trying to do it with `%store` is that the string passed to it is not evaluated but looked up directly in the scope, hence the error `Unknown variable 'eval(i)'`

Comment: It seems working, but gives me `TypeError: can't pickle module objects` if I try to use it in a loop on dir() or locals(). Although it stores the main things with `try` and `except`